# Knockout binding error when trying to delete an item

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.qaTimePoints">
    <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: TimePoint().QaItemTimePoint"></td>
       <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-bind=" click: $root.removeTimePoint">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
           </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have a html table that shows a list of few items and a delete button next to every item. When I click on delete button, removeTimePoint function gets executed in which I have the following line:

```
data.entityAspect.setDeleted()
```

where data is the parameter that the function gets.

After the line is executed, I get the binding error "Unable to parse binding...".

I understand that I am trying to delete an entity which is bound to the html table and hence the error. How can I avoid the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to delete one qaTimePoint entry? If yes, your code should look like:

```
self.removeTimePoint = function(data) { self.qaTimePoints.remove(data) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove removeTimePoint function totally, and bind

```
data-bind="click: $root.qaTimePoints.remove"
```